# Is there a way to use Math.random instead of import java.util.Random but keep the same output

Tags: java

so I want to use Math.random instead of importing java.until.Random but keep the same output of my code

This is my code:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class MyStrings {

    public String randomAlphanumericString(int length) {

        String letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

        String randomWord = "";
        Random random = new Random();
        for (int i = 1; i <= length; i++) {
            randomWord += String.valueOf(letters.charAt(random.nextInt(letters.length())));
        }
        return randomWord;
    }

    public boolean validAlphanumericString(String word) {

        for (char letter : word.toCharArray()) {
            if (Character.isLetter(letter) || Character.isDigit(letter)) {
            } else { System.out.println(word + " contains non alphanumeric characters");
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;

    }


}
```

Comment: Why? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I need to use Math.random for a project instead of import java.util.Random

Comment: I just want to know if it's possible and if so how?

Comment: [Sure](https://stackoverflow.com/a/363732/133203) it's possible. That doesn't mean it's a good idea, tho.

Comment: Will it change up the code a lot if I try to change it?

Comment: You just need to remove the `random` declaration and use the formula instead of `random.nextInt(...)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like:

```
...    
    randomWord += String.valueOf(letters.charAt((int) (Math.random() * letters.length())));
...
```

From the JavaDoc for `Math.random()`:

> Returns a double value with a positive sign, greater than or equal to 0.0 and less than 1.0.

So that's why if you just multiply by the length and truncate it to int you get the range that you need.

Answer (score 0):

If you write a Lambda to get a random value, you can use it just like
`Random.nextInt()`

```
IntFunction<Integer> rand = x-> (int)(Math.random()*x);

int v = rand.apply(10); // value between 0 and 9 inclusive.
```